# ItemizedOverlay issue in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog

ive been trying to pop up a custom dialog box when tapping on a marker of the google map. I use this code to override onTap() method of itemizedOverlay calss.

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            AlertDialog alertDialog;

            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

            TextView textName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textName.setText("Here is the Name");

            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setView(layout);

            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            return super.onTap(index);
        }
```

Here is the custom dialog layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
```

But i get this exception when tapping on a marker

```
02-07 16:46:51.768: E/AndroidRuntime(315): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

this is the exact example given on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

any help please...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classname.this instead of getApplicationContext 
if its a simple mapactivity

if its in tab then use getParent()

because badtokenexception occur when its not take right class reference.

Comment: Thanks Newts :) that exactly was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```